# Electron Builder with React: Getting __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I'm using Electron Builder to package my React app, but I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED')
at 289 (react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js:10:136)
at d (bootstrap:19:22)
at 115 (jsx-runtime.js:4:20)
at d (bootstrap:19:22)
at make namespace object:6:63
at index.tsx:8:17
at index.tsx:8:17
at universalModuleDefinition:7:233
at universalModuleDefinition:1:1
```

The error seems to be originating from the last line of `index.tsx` which is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { All_Channels } from '../main/preload';

const container = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement;
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

My build structure is like so:

```
release
├── app
├── dist
│   └── main
│       ├── main.js
│       ├── main.js.map
│       ├── preload.js
│       └── preload.js.map
└── renderer
    ├── index.html
    ├── renderer.js
    ├── renderer.js.LICENSE.txt
    ├── renderer.js.map
    ├── search.html
    ├── style.css
    └── style.css.map
node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

I see React in the node_modules of the dist so I'm not sure why it's not finding my app. I'm on an Silicon Mac

Here is my Electron-Builder config, it is set as a 'build' property in the package.json:

```
"build": {
"productName": "ElectronReact",
"appId": "org.erb.ElectronReact",
"asar": true,
"asarUnpack": "**\\*.{node,dll}",
"afterSign": ".erb/scripts/notarize.js",
"mac": {
  "target": {
    "target": "default",
    "arch": [
      "arm64"
    ]
  },
  "type": "distribution",
  "hardenedRuntime": true,
  "entitlements": "assets/entitlements.mac.plist",
  "entitlementsInherit": "assets/entitlements.mac.plist",
  "gatekeeperAssess": false
},
"dmg": {
  "contents": [
    {
      "x": 130,
      "y": 220
    },
    {
      "x": 410,
      "y": 220,
      "type": "link",
      "path": "/Applications"
    }
  ]
},
"win": {
  "target": [
    "nsis"
  ]
},
"linux": {
  "target": [
    "AppImage"
  ],
  "category": "Development"
},
"directories": {
  "app": "release/app",
  "buildResources": "assets",
  "output": "release/build"
},
"extraResources": [
  "./assets/**"
],
"includeSubNodeModules": true,
"publish": {
  "provider": "github",
  "owner": "electron-react-boilerplate",
  "repo": "electron-react-boilerplate"
}}
```

Comment: Did you forget quotes around the angle brackets?

Comment: @MadPhysicist around <App /> in root.render?

Comment: I have no idea, but maybe. Also, please don't post images of text

Comment: @MadPhysicist Okay my bad, was being lazy, updated it, but render takes in a ReactNode so it has to be that way

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you package your app as well as share your electron-builder config?

Comment: @Arkellys good point, my bad, I should have added it earlier, done

Comment: You used `electron-react-boilerplate` to create your app, so I see you use the `build` config defined by it. Most of it seems unnecessary to me, but you removed the `files` option, which is most probably needed in your case.

Comment: @Arkellys You're right I was missing that, but I copied and pasted the package.json from the boilerplate repo and replaced mine entirely and it still didn't work. It might be something with the Webpack files, going to try that next

Comment: Okay that error is gone, now it's saying an error inside my code so I think I made progress. It was the webpacks that I had modified that was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

@Arkellys put me on the right path. The package.json adding `files` didn't fix it (but it was a factor). In order to fix another bug, I had modified something in one of the webpack files which caused this now.

I went to [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/tree/main/.erb/configs) and changed all of my webpack files to the original ones. Silly mistake on my end...